# Which array syntax is more efficient?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, performance

**I did not find similar question**

## 1

```
$form['level1']['level2'][] = array(
    'data' => 'some data',
    'type' => 'some type',
);
//etc
```

## 2

```
 $form = array(
   'level1' => array(
      'level2' => array(
         array(
            'data' => 'some data',
            'type' => 'some type',
         ), 
         //etc
       ),
    ),
 );
```

Comment: 2 is more readable than 1.

Comment: For the number of picoseconds difference that this will make to your scripts, efficiency is largely an irrelevance.... ask yourself instead "which is more readable?"

Comment: Version 1 will give you a notice/warning if `$form['level1']['level2']` is not already an array.

Comment: I agree, same to efficiency? I am working with Drupal and it has a lot of nested large arrays, I am just curiuos

Comment: imho 1 is more readable than 2, but as stated, you would need to define $form['level1']['level2'] as an array first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely microoptimizing...

```
Test 1: 9.0906839370728
Test 2: 8.5538339614868
```

But the second is more efficient. For example `[]` is slower as it first has to check for the last index etc...
Also the first has to first check if the array already exists (at every dimension) while in the second case it is clear to PHP that there is a new array.

P.s.: But I don't really know, as the first is less to parse than the second. The parser time I didn't measure... (And I don't suppose that the arrays are now very often recreated?)

Answer (score -1):

2 is more readable than 1.

Also, if you going to play without warning, 1 would be:

```
$arr = array();
$arr["level1"] = array();
$arr["level1"]["level2"] = array();
//... etc
```

Comment: Which also makes #1 less efficient - because each level/block has to be separately defined

Comment: What warnings are you referring to specifically?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined offset`

Comment: Disagree, e.g: $new_array["level1"]["level2"][] = 'value' give you correct nested array without any notices (E_ALL)